# Which OWASP modsecurity crs version to install on apache 2.2.22

Tags: apache, owasp, mod-security

Hello I am considering installing owasp mod_security crs on an ubuntu 12.04.4 which comes with apache 2.2.22. On the github page I have seen many version's but all tutorials were using `2.2.7`

First I figured it's because the posts are using the available version at the time of writing .

Is there any caveat using version 3.0.0 in apache 2.2.22? Since I have used 2.2.7 before I wanted to ask some one who has gone down this path (3.0.0) before going ahead

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there native mod_security package for Ubuntu? I installed Apche httpd 2.15 with Mod Security version 2.7 in Cent OS 6.

Comment: Hello I was rather referring to owasp mod security crs not the mod security itself